# remote management will restore the user keyboard mapping under M1

Tags: mac, keyboard

For coding I'd like to use an external keyboard and exchange the <kbd>Opt</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key,

[image]

But after I remote manage my Mac from another PC, the keyboard mapping will be restored like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve it?